# Adding a counter to a string when inputting values to a record structure using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, data-structures

Here is the structure that has been created:

```
Structure Test
    <VBFixedString(4)> Public TestID As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word1 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue1 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word2 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue2 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word3 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue3 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word4 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue4 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word5 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue5 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word6 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue6 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word7 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue7 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word8 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue8 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word9 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue9 As String

    <VBFixedString(15)> Public Word10 As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Public Clue10 As String
End Structure
```

And these are the loops that I am trying to get to work:

```
    i = 1
    y = 0


    Do Until y = 9
        SpellingTest.Word & (i) = ArrayWord(y)
        i = i + 1
        y = i - 1
    Loop

    i = 1
    y = 0

    Do Until y = 9
        SpellingTest.Clue & (i) = ArrayClue(y)
        i = i + 1
        y = i - 1
    Loop
```

I am trying to get `i` to be the number on the end of the field. However, this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access a value by name string like that is to use reflection.

So using your code something like the following should work:

```
    Dim myType As Type = SpellingTest.GetType
    Dim pinfo As PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty("Word" & i.ToString)

    pinfo.SetValue(SpellingTest, ArrayWord(y), Nothing)
```

MSDN Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9(v=vs.110).aspx